# CSS Marquee on MS Edge

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge, marquee

I found [this awesome CSS-Marquee](http://jsfiddle.net/MaY5A/209/) and it works almost on every Browser, but unfortunately not on MS Edge. When you hover over the Marquee is should stop, but Edge don't like

```
.marquee span:hover
{
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

It's even worse, because Edge makes it impossible to mark the text in the Marquee and all Links in the Marquee are broken.

Here is the full code:

```
<div class="marquee">
  <span>Some long text with a few <a href="#">Links</a> and bla bla</span>
</div>

/* define the animation */
@keyframes marquee
{
    0%   { transform: translate(0, 0); }
    100% { transform: translate(-100%, 0); }
}

/* define your limiting container */
.marquee
{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* this is the tray moving around your container */
.marquee span
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 100%;
    text-indent: 0;
    animation: marquee 60s linear infinite; /* here you select the animation */
}

/* pause the animation on mouse over */
.marquee span:hover
{
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

Any Solutions for that ? Maybe a separate CSS for Edge?
And is it possible to make the animation speed the same for different text length?

EDIT:
OK ! So i found a way to make the speed the same with different text lenght:

```
<script>
function calcSpeed(speed) {
// Time = Distance/Speed
var spanSelector = document.querySelector('.marquee span');
var spanLength = spanSelector.offsetWidth;
var timeTaken = spanLength / speed;
spanSelector.style.animationDuration = timeTaken + "s";
}
calcSpeed(100);
</script>
```

But there is still the problem, that Edge don't like "animation-play-state: paused;" and break all the Links in the Marquee

Comment: I don't know if it's possible for CSS to target Edge only, but you could try something like putting the animation part in `.marquee span:not(:hover)` so that you can avoid `animation-play-state`.

Comment: This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

Comment: I don't use the old default <marquee> !!! It's a CSS animation !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok ! This is my solution !
It has now the same speed with different text length and i overwrite the css if Edge is used. Now the Marquee stops at almost every Browser if you hover over the Marquee and in Edge the animation-play-state: paused; is changed to animation-play-state: running;

Here is the code for the same speed:

```
<script>
function calcSpeed(speed) {
// Time = Distance/Speed
var spanSelector = document.querySelector('.marquee span');
var spanLength = spanSelector.offsetWidth;
var timeTaken = spanLength / speed;
spanSelector.style.animationDuration = timeTaken + "s";
}
calcSpeed(100);
</script>
```

And here is the code for Edge:

```
@supports (-ms-ime-align:auto) {
  .marquee span:hover { animation-play-state: running; } 
}
```

If you have a better solution for that where the animation stops with Edge, than pls post it!!!